# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на элемент раскрывалось меню?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста. Весь мозг себе сломал - и ничего не выходит...

Нужно, чтобы при наведении на `<a href="#">Скорей Домой</a>`   открывалось `<li class="sub" id="sub4">`.

Вот код:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="description" content="description">

<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jquery.css" />
<script src="http://teste123reee.ucoz.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu li").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "-100px" }, 400);
        },function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 400);
        });

 });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="top">Гавная</a><a href="#">Скорей Домой</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div class="example">
    <ul class="menu">
        <!-- Верхние пункты -->

        <li class="main" id="has-sub4"><a target="_blank" href="#">Открывающиеся <br>Меню</a></li>

        <!-- Подпункты -->

        <li class="sub" id="sub4">
            <table><tr>
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Ссылки x</dt>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Ссылки x</dt>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Ссылки x</dt>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Ссылки x</dt>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                        <dd><a target="_blank" href="#">Ссылка x</a></dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            </tr></table>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Это CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Основные стили меню */

body,html{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;   }

#menu {
    height:5%; width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10% auto;
    text-align: center;
    background:#099;
    font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    min-height:35px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.2%;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 16%;
height: 50%;

}
#menu ul {
    width: 100%;

}
/* Стили ссылок меню */
#menu ul a.top {
    background: black; color: #008000;
    font: 1.5vw/170% "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#menu ul a {
    display: block;
    background: red; color: #fff;
    height: 100px; width: 100%;
    font: lighter 1.5vw/170% "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;

}

--------------Всплывающее----------

.example{
height:100%; width: 100%;
background:#0C3 !important;
border:#006 2px !important;
    }

.menu {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    min-height:35px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    height:10% !important; width:50% !important;
    z-index:1;
    background: #033;
    left:20%;
    margin-top:15%;
}

.menu li{

    }
.menu li.main {
    height:10% !important; width:100% !important;
    padding-right:1px;
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    z-index:1;
    left:0%;
    margin-top:5%;
    background:#0C3;

}

.menu li.main a {
    font:1.4vw/60% "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-4%;
    left:43%;

}

.block1:hover + .block2 { visibility: visible; }

.menu li.sub {
    background-color:#444;
    border:0;
    clear:both;
    float:center;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;

    -moz-transform-origin: left top !important;
    -ms-transform-origin: left top !important;
    -o-transform-origin: left top !important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top !important;
    transform-origin: left top  !important;

    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out ;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;

    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.menu li.sub table {
    width:100%
}
.menu li.sub dl {
    background-color:#fff;
    height:195px;
    margin:5px 5px 0 0;
    padding:10px;

    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px
}
.menu li.sub dt {
    border:1px solid #000;
    color:#000;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:18px;
    margin:1px 0;
    padding:0 10px;

    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px
}
.menu li.sub dt:hover {
    background-color:#ccc
}
.menu li.sub dd {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.menu li.sub dd a {

    color:#666;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
    text-decoration:none;

    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px
}
.menu li.sub dd a:hover {
    background-color:#ccc;
    color:#444
}
.menu li#has-sub4:hover ~ li#sub4 {
    height:270px;

    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
}

li#sub4:hover {
    height:250px;

    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s
}
```

Comment: @assasin84, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте `<a href="#">Скорей Домой</a>` на `<a href="#" id="link1">Скорей Домой</a>`

Скрипт поменяйте на:

```
$("#link1").hover(function() {
     $("#sub4").stop().animate({ marginTop: "-100px" }, 400);
},function(){
     $("#sub4").stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Поменял вторую ссылку и скрипт..И ничего не вышло!Мне нужно чтобы этот скрипт который стоит срабатывал,т.е чтобы поворачивал на вторую ссылку при наведении и еще чтобы открывалось доп.меню при наведении на `<a href="#">Скорей Домой</a>` ..это       `<li class="sub" id="sub4">`     ..Пробовал разные комбинации но чтото невыходит!

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий пример горизонтальное меню - http://jemand.ru/gorizontalnoe-vypadayushhee-menyu-na-css/ там и ссылка есть на демо можно посмотреть - это вертикально меню http://olocoder.ru/CSS15.html Welcome